# EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException by Jasypt with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, bouncycastle, jasypt

I try to use [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) with [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/index.html) crypro provides (128Bit AES) in a Spring Application to decrypt entity properties while saving them with Hibernate. But I always get this `org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException` when try to save the entrity.

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException
  Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using strong encryption
  algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited
  Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.handleInvalidKeyException(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1073)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.encrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:924)
at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.encrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:642)
at org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.AbstractEncryptedAsStringType.nullSafeSet(AbstractEncryptedAsStringType.java:155)
at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:158)
```

*(full stacktrace below)*

I do not use Java Cryptography Extension (JCE), thats why I try to use [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/index.html)

**I think there is something wrong with the spring configuration, does anybody find the problem?**

My spring Configuration is:

```
<bean id="bouncyCastleProvider" class="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"/>
<bean class="org.jasypt.hibernate4.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor" depends-on="bouncyCastleProvider">

    <property name="provider" ref="bouncyCastleProvider"/>  
    <property name="providerName" value="BC"/>

    <property name="saltGenerator">
        <bean class="org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator"/>
    </property>

    <property name="registeredName" value="STRING_ENCRYPTOR"/>      
    <property name="algorithm" value="PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC"/>
    <property name="password" value="sEcRET1234"/>
</bean>
```

Usage:

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "encryptedString", typeClass = EncryptedStringType.class, parameters = { @Parameter(name = "encryptorRegisteredName", value = "STRING_ENCRYPTOR") })
public class SubscriptionProcess {
  ...      
   @Type(type = "encryptedString")
   private String debitAccountIban;
  ...
}
```

pom/dependenies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-hibernate4</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
 ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <!-- I use an older version of bouncy castle that is also used by tika  -->
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>           
        <version>1.45</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>           
        <version>1.45</version>
    </dependency>
```

Full Stack Trace

```
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using strong encryption algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.handleInvalidKeyException(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:1073)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.encrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:924)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.encrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:642)
    at org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.AbstractEncryptedAsStringType.nullSafeSet(AbstractEncryptedAsStringType.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2818)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3025)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3556)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:807)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.demo.base.user.BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil$Persistent.postCreate(BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.java:424)
    at com.demo.base.user.BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.createSafeCustodyAccount(BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.java:321)
    at com.demo.base.user.BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.createSafeCustodyAccount(BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.java:329)
    at com.demo.base.user.BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.createSafeCustodyAccount(BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.java:333)
    at com.demo.base.user.BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.createUserWithSafeCustodyAccount(BaseUserDomainCreatorUtil.java:128)
    at com.demo.app.asset.AssetTestScenario.<init>(AssetTestScenario.java:66)
    at com.demo.app.asset.dao.SubscriptionProcessDaoSpringTest.testPersistence_aroundBody0(SubscriptionProcessDaoSpringTest.java:62)
    at com.demo.app.asset.dao.SubscriptionProcessDaoSpringTest$AjcClosure1.run(SubscriptionProcessDaoSpringTest.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:60)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:64)
    at com.demo.app.asset.dao.SubscriptionProcessDaoSpringTest.testPersistence(SubscriptionProcessDaoSpringTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/features.html) is designed to be used with `JCE providers`, the terminology that this project uses on its web may be confusing you since there is the follow sentence:

> Open API for use with any JCE provider, and not only the default Java
>   VM one. Jasypt can be easily used with well-known providers like
>   Bouncy Castle

From this sentence maybe you're understanding that Jasypt can be used with `JCE` or with BouncyCastle like both are working differently or something like that; however, what this sentence means is that there are many `JCE providers`, default providers which come with default java installation and non-default ones, however both accomplish the [`JCA/JCE` specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Provider)  and both can work with Jasypt.

As I said BouncyCastle has a `JCE provider`, from the [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) you can see:

> A provider for the Java Cryptography Extension and the Java
>   Cryptography Architecture.

So if you're trying to make encrypt/decrypt operations using `org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider` as provider you've got the same restrictions that all `JCE` providers have, respect to available algorithms and key length.

To avoid this restrictions about key length and algorithms and to pass the errors you have, you must install `Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files` for your jvm version.

For example for java 1.7 you can download the files from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html). And then copy the jars in $JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security overwriting the existing `local_policy.jar` and `US_export_policy.jar`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **JRE home** path(right click windows->preferences->click the location -> check the **JRE home** path is pointing **jdk** or not ) if it points jre please change it to **jdk**.